# jQuery assign images to consecutive elements

Tags: jquery

I have below div with 4 blank images (images are coming from background url)

```
    <div style="float: left; display: block; width: 50%;">
        <p>Choose 4 Club Items</p>
        <br>
        <a href="#product_grid"><span class="empty-plus-container"><img src="criteria1"></span></a>
        <a href="#product_grid"><span class="empty-plus-container"><img src="criteria1"></span></a>
        <a href="#product_grid"><span class="empty-plus-container"><img src="criteria1"></span></a>
        <a href="#product_grid"><span class="empty-plus-container"><img src="criteria1"></span></a>
    </div>
```

Below I have product grid with "Add" button.

Now when I add 1st product, I want the product image to be filled in 1st element.

Similarly when I add multiple products, their images should be filled in next elements.

I tried with below function but it is filling all the elements at once.

```
        var items = document.getElementsByName('criteria1');

        for(var x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {

            items[x].setAttribute("src","second.jpg");

        }
```

Any idea how to do this one by one instead of all at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can give different id to each image tag 
and in loop you can get the id of particulate image tag and then using some if else condition you can easily assign src to the image tag which you want